# Swapping two numbers without outside variables and output to div

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to swap two numbers without using outside variables, using `div` for output, but it will add zero to one of my numbers.

For example if my input is `1 2`, it'll print `2 10`:

```js
function swap() {
    num2.value = num1.value + (num1.value = num2.value) - num2.value;
    divID.innerHTML = num1.value + " " + num2.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="num1"/>
<input id="num2"/>
<button onclick="swap()">click</button> 
<div id="divID">output here</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to [vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on answers that were helpful, and accepting one if it addressed your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Another few methods:

```
var a = 5, b = 4;
a = a + b; // a now becomes 9
b = a - b; // b becomes 5
a = a - b; // a becomes 4

var a = 5, b = 4;
a = a ^ b; // a now becomes 1
b = a ^ b; // b becomes 5
a = a ^ b; // a becomes 4

var a = 5, b = 4;
a = a * b; // a now becomes 20
b = a / b; // b becomes 5
a = a / b; // a becomes 4
```

Comment: super!
I'll adopt those:)

Comment: When using summations and multiplications, some underflowing or overflowing can occur. But bitwise operations(like the second example of yours) are exact.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example for swapping without some other variable than the two. This is possible with a temporary array, an assignment and a prompt access of the 0th element.

```
a = [b, b = a][0];
```

Or with a smaller footprint

```
a = [b][b = a, 0];
```

Working example:

```js
var a = 5, b = 42;
a = [b, b = a][0];
document.write('a: ' + a + '<br>');
document.write('b: ' + b);
```

The problem you had, was a wrong formula (and some type mismatch).

```js
function swap() {
    num2.value = +num1.value - +num2.value + (num1.value = +num2.value);
    divID.innerHTML = num1.value + " " + num2.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="num1"/>
<input id="num2"/>
<button onclick="swap()">click</button> 
<div id="divID">output here</div>
```

Comment: works superb
but what it means when you write "+num1.value" and "+num2.value" 
what the plus for ?

Comment: it cast the value to `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Xor swap

```
a=5; b=4;
a^=b;  // now a is 1, b is 4
b^=a;  // now a is 1, b is 5
a^=b;  // now a is 4, b is 5
```

they are swapped by just bitwise operations on each bit of two variables. Note that this works for only same bit lengths of two numbers.

No extra memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable as storage:

```
function swap(){

    var temp = num2.value;
    num2.value = num1.value;
    num1.value = temp;

    divID.innerHTML=num1.value+" "+num2.value;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the div's innerHTML as a temporary storage:

```js
function swap() {
    divID.innerHTML = num1.value;
    num1.value = num2.value;
    num2.value = divID.innerHTML;
    divID.innerHTML = num1.value + " " + num2.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="num1"/ value="1">
<input id="num2"/ value="2">
<button onclick="swap()">swap</button> 
<div id="divID">output here</div>
```